# The area between the graphs $f_t(x)=e^{x-t}-t$ and $g_t(x)=\log(x+t)+t$ is irrational only if $t$ is irrational.

Tags: calculus

> Find the smallest $t \in \mathbb{R}$ such that the graphs of $f_t:x\mapsto \exp(x-t)-t$ and $g_t:x\mapsto\log(x+t)+t$ intersect. Note that $\log$ is meant as the natural logarithm.

Hint: I guess it's $\frac{1}{2}$.

Now the real problem (it's hard):

> Prove or disprove: whenever the area $A$ between $f_t$ and $g_t$ exists and $A \in \mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Q}$ then $t\in \mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: To what base is the log intended?

Comment: where does the real problem come from?

Comment: $\log$ is meant to be the natural logarithm.

Comment: Why include the not-real part of the problem?

Comment: @I.Padilla, [no there isn't](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/sbsvdlrgrs)

Comment: Did you come up with a formula relating t and A?

Answer (score 0):

You can prove that $\frac 12$ is indeed the minimal value of $t$, by showing that there is only one solution to $$e^{x-\frac12}-\frac12=\ln(x+\frac12)+\frac12$$.

Comment: Okay but lets say we dont know that $\frac{1}{2}$ is the solution. How do you get to $\frac{1}{2}$?

Comment: Personally I plotted it graphically. I'm sure however you could take an algebraic approach to show for which value of $t$ the equation only has one solution. Whats also worth noting is that $f_t(x)=g_t^{-1}(x)$ so any solutions occur on the line $y=x$

Answer (score 0):

Assume it to be true, then

If $t \in \mathbb{Q} \Rightarrow $  Area between $f$ and $g$ $\in \mathbb{Q}$

Then specially for $t = 0$

$$
\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{x}- \log(x) dx = \left[x+  e^x + x (-\log (x)) \right]_{0}^{\infty} = \\
 \lim_{x \to \infty} x +  e^x + x (-\log (x)) - \lim_{x \ \to 0 } x+  e^x + x (-\log (x)) = \infty
$$